# Solve the recursion

Tags: recursion

I am trying to solve the recursion T (n) = T (n/5) + n^2
and I cant figure out after following step.

```
T (k) = T (k/5) + k^2    
= (T(k/25) + k^2/25) + k^2
= (T(k/625) + k^2/625) + k^2/25 + k^2
= T(1) + … + k^2/625 + k^2/25 + k^2
= k^2+ k^2/25+ k^2/625 +…+ T(1)
= k^2(1 + 1/25 + 1/625 + …)
```

Comment: This is not a programming problem, it's a mathematical one, probably best asked in a [dedicated forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/).  Two hints, though. First, you're missing the base case.  Second you have a term that's an infinite geometric series.  There's a simple value for those.

Comment: Thanks! The base case is T(1) = constant